# innerHTML not working properly

Tags: javascript, html

this is my first posting on the forum, so please be kind and let me know, if I made some sort of mistake.

So I'm working on a website, that dynamically changes it's contents, which come from a SQL-database. I managed to receive the data from the server as a JSON-file and my next task is to fill the pages DOM-elements with the received content. The problem is, that my **innerHTML**-commands don't seem to work, whereas my the parts where I change the **href** of a element do work. I'm really confused and can't seem to find out what the problem is.
Maybe you can help me.

The HTML looks somewhat like this, just imagine there being five os there elements:

```
<div id="fact_0">
    <img id="fact_0_icon" src="media/icons/icon_1.svg"/>
    <p id="fact_0_text"></p> 
    <img id="fact_0_article" src="media/icons/icon_2.svg"/>
</div>
```

The Javascript looks as follows:

```
function documentChange (data) {
    for(let i=0;i<5;i++) {
        document.getElementById("fact_"+i+"_text").innerHMTL= data[i].text;
        document.getElementById("fact_"+i+"_icon").setAttribute("src", "media/icons/"+data[i].icon+".svg");
        document.getElementById("fact_"+i+"_share").setAttribute("href", data[i].url);
        switch(data[i].category) {
            case "1":
                document.getElementById("fact_"+i+"_icon").style.color="#4cc40f";
                break;
            case "2":
                document.getElementById("fact_"+i+"_icon").style.color="#6767d2";
                break;
            case "3": 
                document.getElementById("fact_"+i+"_icon").style.color="#08B8DA";
                break;
            case "4": 
                document.getElementById("fact_"+i+"_icon").style.color="#e60909";
                break;
            case "5":
                document.getElementById("fact_"+i+"_icon").style.color="#a72aa4";
                break;
            default: 
                document.getElementById("fact_"+i+"_icon").style.color="#4cc40f";}}}
```

Comment: It's a typo, you have wrote "innerHMTL", it should be innerHTML.

Comment: yiou are using innerHMTL its innerHTML

Comment: You have spelling mistake at

document.getElementById("fact_"+i+"_text").innerHMTL= data[i].text;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo: you type **`HMTL`** instead of **`HTML`**.

So use `.innerHTML` instead of `.innerHMTL`.

Here's the full solution:

```
function documentChange (data) {
    for(let i=0;i<5;i++) {
        document.getElementById("fact_"+i+"_text").innerHTML= data[i].text;
        var icon = document.getElementById("fact_"+i+"_icon");
        icon.src = "media/icons/"+data[i].icon+".svg";
        //document.getElementById("fact_"+i+"_icon").setAttribute("src", "media/icons/"+data[i].icon+".svg");
        document.getElementById("fact_"+i+"_share").setAttribute("href", data[i].url);
        switch(data[i].category) {
            case "1":
                document.getElementById("fact_"+i+"_icon").style.color="#4cc40f";
                break;
            case "2":
                document.getElementById("fact_"+i+"_icon").style.color="#6767d2";
                break;
            case "3": 
                document.getElementById("fact_"+i+"_icon").style.color="#08B8DA";
                break;
            case "4": 
                document.getElementById("fact_"+i+"_icon").style.color="#e60909";
                break;
            case "5":
                document.getElementById("fact_"+i+"_icon").style.color="#a72aa4";
                break;
            default: 
                document.getElementById("fact_"+i+"_icon").style.color="#4cc40f";}}}
```

Comment: Oh god! Thank you. That's embarrassing. Since I forgot to ask, the line below also doesn't work. The src-attribute doesn't change.In addition the style-command in my switch-cases don't work. I expect to be embarrassed again.

Comment: I edited to make src work. And `element.style.color` affects the text color only ([from W3S](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_color.asp))

Comment: Okay so not it doesn't work as i planned. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

It is your typing mistake.

Use `.innerHTML` and rerun it.

```
document.getElementById("fact_"+i+"_text").innerHTML= data[i].text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this with your line 
`document.getElementById("fact_"+i+"_text").innerHTML= data[i].text;`

Comment: @sudo now it's allright i think.